# For Wordpress - How to call get_current_user_id in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a calendar script that is done completely in javascript. I need to pass it a user ID from wordpress and typically I can get that ID using get_current_user_id() but because this is javascript I'm a little at a loss as to how to do it. I thought AJAX might work, but not sure how to put that together and it needs to happen on page load whereas AJAX is for user actions on a page. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Could possibly be done using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a hidden element with that as the value.
Then access the element in javascript and retrieve the value.

Comment: the html for the form is also generated in javascript :/

Comment: You can still put an arbitrary element on the page somewhere just to hold the value. Think of it as a custom placeholder.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous? Someone can change the value via the DOM and then someone else's user ID will be used?

Comment: Swapping IDs is a risk for _anything_ that happens client-side - that's why you have to do validation on the form submission to make sure the user is authorized.

Also, you can inject things _directly_ into javascript variables if you use WordPress functions wp_register_script, wp_localize_script, and wp_enqueue_script.